# Linux 3.0 x86_64: When is SIGSTKFLT raised?

Tags: c, linux, signals, gnu, x86-64

Under what circumstances (if any) would the signal SIGSTKFLT be synchronously raised by the kernel under Linux 3.0 on x86_64 ?

Comment: It probably never would. Why do you ask?

Comment: Trying to write an appropriate error message for it in a system library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `man 7 signal`:

```
 Signal       Value     Action   Comment

SIGSTKFLT    -,16,-     Term    Stack fault on coprocessor (unused)
```

Since the x86 coprocessor stack cannot fault (I'm pretty sure), I don't think it can be signaled implicitly.  Only explicit generation (by `kill()` or `raise()`) could cause it.

I `grep`'d the kernel source.  It does not use it, but there are about 50 instances (per CPU architecture) of

```
#define SIGSTKFLT   16
```

Comment: Well the x87 coprocessor can fault: just unmask IM bit in FPU Control Word and try to execute `fld` instruction 9 times without `fstp` or similar ones. But on Linux such a stack fault generates SIGFPE instead of SIGSTKFLT.

Comment: @Ruslan:  I meant I didn't think the 8087 can generate a SIGSTKFLT.  Of course it can create other types of faults like a SIGSEGV, etc.

Comment: No, I mean it can really literally have a stack fault (its 8 registers are organized in a stack), although this doesn't reflect on how Linux reports such errors — for the app they are just SIGFPE.

Comment: @Ruslan That's probably what this signal was intended for. What a shame that it isn't actually used, this would have made my Forth interpreter much easier to program.